I'm getting an Import error but within a Python file using fastapi but it works fine if I run the python file manually
So as of now I'm working on a FastAPI project. You can view the file tree here

In the classification pipeline file are the following lines:
import requests
from typing import Dict, List 

from prompts import (
    json_example, json_extractor_prompt, 
    definitions, 
)

import re 
import json 

Where it imports from the variables from the prompts.py file.
When I run the file using uvicorn main:app -reload
It doesn't work and throws the following error
(ast) ➜  project-astra git:(main) ✗ uvicorn main:app --reload
INFO:     Will watch for changes in these directories: ['/home/kyojinprat/project-astra']
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:     Started reloader process [18196] using WatchFiles
Process SpawnProcess-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 314, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/kyojinprat/project-astra/ast/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uvicorn/_subprocess.py", line 80, in subprocess_started
    target(sockets=sockets)
  File "/home/kyojinprat/project-astra/ast/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uvicorn/server.py", line 65, in run
    return asyncio.run(self.serve(sockets=sockets))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "uvloop/loop.pyx", line 1518, in uvloop.loop.Loop.run_until_complete
  File "/home/kyojinprat/project-astra/ast/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uvicorn/server.py", line 69, in serve
    await self._serve(sockets)
  File "/home/kyojinprat/project-astra/ast/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uvicorn/server.py", line 76, in _serve
    config.load()
  File "/home/kyojinprat/project-astra/ast/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uvicorn/config.py", line 434, in load
    self.loaded_app = import_from_string(self.app)
  File "/home/kyojinprat/project-astra/ast/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uvicorn/importer.py", line 22, in import_from_string
    raise exc from None
  File "/home/kyojinprat/project-astra/ast/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uvicorn/importer.py", line 19, in import_from_string
    module = importlib.import_module(module_str)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/kyojinprat/project-astra/main.py", line 24, in <module>
    from data_classifier.classification_pipeline import get_json
  File "/home/kyojinprat/project-astra/data_classifier/classification_pipeline.py", line 4, in <module>
    from prompts import (
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'prompts'


But when I run python data_classifier/classification_pipeline.py
It works.
What exactly is happening?
The surprising thing is, the endpoints were working yesterday. So it's most likely some changes made by my that caused it. But I don't understand what could that possibly be. I will send more snippets if you require

When you run FastAPI app with uvicorn, it starts the app from main.py rather than directly executing your script. The working directory is likely set to the project root (project-astra), so python tries to find the prompts module from this folder. If it can't find it, you get the ModuleNotFoundError.
Try to add a . before prompts in classification_pipeline:
from .prompts import (
    json_example, json_extractor_prompt, 
    definitions
)

This will make python look for prompts inside the current pack where is classification_pipeline.py
